# How can I send two variables in python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am wondering How to send two variables in python socket. I am currently doing it but the way in which I am sending them can make it so if it misses one send then they switch which variable is which, which is very bad for my purpose. Is there a way I can label the variables so I send both kinda as if I were to label a variable y and on x send the variable with the label and then separate it on the other side, Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This question is more about communication protocols than about python programming.

If you want reliable communication, use TCP sockets rather than UDP. Also, encode your messages in a form that keeps the identity of what you're sending together with the values.

JSON based example:

```
import json
sock.send(json.dumps({"x":x, "y":y}))
```

Also, you could consider a communications framework like ZeroMQ to take care of the data delivery for you.